# sorting numerically by first row - bash

Tags: bash, sorting, terminal

I have a file with roughly 1000 lines of data that I want to numerically sort depending on the value of the first column. I use

```
sort -k1 -n file.txt
```

However, certain numbers, such as 2e-2 and 1.5e-5..., all end up at the end of the file. This sort command, I mean, does not comprehend the meaning of "e" in the values. How can I make it correct?

Comment: `-n` is "integer" numeric. I cannot test ATM, but I see `sort` has a `-g` option for "general" numeric search: perhaps this will help?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried -g option, and it is working